# How to prevent Dashcode from renaming label-strings after save operation [iBook Author related]?

Tags: dashcode

For use in iBooks Author, I created a widget with Dashcode.

The widget some labels:

[image: Before Save operation]

If I save the widget within Dashcode, the windows flickers a bit (updates) - and all labels suddenly appear with the same text:

[image: After Save operation]

Please note, that the widget doesn't create any JS code yet.

**How to prevent Dashcode from 'unifying' the string?**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013907/why-are-some-widget-elements-not-showing-up-when-embedded-in-ibook) is probably helpful for [Dashcode/iBook Author users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013907/why-are-some-widget-elements-not-showing-up-when-embedded-in-ibook) too [and my [similar question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071975/how-to-use-dashcode-widgets-in-ibooks-author).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the cause of the problem:

- **Don't clone  - copy & paste - a text label.**

Somehow, they get connected :-(